# How to get the absolute folder location of a Jmeter .jmx project file from within itself?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a Jmeter project that is executed by Maven and is able to locate external Beanshell scripts by the path `src/test/jmeter/external-scripts-dir/script1.bsh` , but when I run Jmeter directly in the GUI on my computer the relative location doesn't work and the tests cannot be ran standalone.   This forces me to run Jmeter from Maven.

So, I have a project file located at a Maven layout location like `C:\files\git\projectA\src\test\jmeter\Project.jmx` but since I ran jmeter from its installation folder at  `C:\Jmeter2.12` ,  it cannot find the relative location of the external script I mentioned earlier.

To solve this, all I need is to set a variable to the directory containing the .jmx  file.   Is there any possible way to do this?

I can dynamically determine the home of Jmeter ( `C:\Jmeter2.12` ) pretty easily (using the following code) but that doesn't help me get the location of the project file.

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer
  .getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}
```

Is there something similar to the above code that would allow me to deduce the project file location?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but did you know that you can run JMeter in GUI mode using the meter-maven plugin?

Just go into your project and do:

    mvn jmeter:gui

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36860307/3940047 - to get jmx test plan file location for both GUI / Non GUI mode executions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking for the way to locate current script when you run JMeter in GUI mode you can try the following Beanshell expression:

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();)}
```

If you brake this down into 5 lines there will be:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
String testPlanFile = GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();
String testPlanFileDir = FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(testPlanFile);
vars.put("testPlanFileDir", testPlanFileDir);
log.info("testPlanFileDir:" + testPlanFileDir);
```

Your current .jmx file fill be stored as `scriptFile` JMeter Variable.

References:

- GuiPackage class [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/gui/GuiPackage.html#getTestPlanFile())
- [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide

Comment: This works when running the test from the JMeter GUI. For running from Maven, @djangofan's suggestion helped.

Answer (score 8):

The solution was (thanks to Ardesco) to do the following:

Use the following variables, set in the Test Plan global variables:

```
projectHome = ${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}
jmeterHome = ${__BeanShell(System.getProperty("user.dir");)}
scriptHome = ${projectHome}/scripts
```

Comment: You can get properties with the __P syntax, so jmeterHome can be simplified to ${__P(user.dir)}

Comment: What you get here is the bin folder of the Jmeter environment, not the location of the JMX file.

Comment: @ShaiAlon `projectHome` is where the jmx file resides, while `jmeterHome` is actually the bin folder of the JMeter environment.

Comment: @acejazz you are correct. However, the question after all was how to get the folder of the JMX file and not the bin folder.

Comment: jmeterHome is NOT the `bin` folder of the environment if you launch JMeter correctly, from the root of the JMeter install by running  `./bin/jmeter` .  If you setup your path correctly, this is effectively what you should have.   I know this is often misunderstood, such as with the jmeter-maven-plugin, which uses /bin as the home.

Comment: the jmeter-maven-plugin does not use the bin directory as JMETER_HOME, it treats `target/<GUID>/jmeter` as JMETER_HOME. look in the config.json in the target dir after running the configure goal with the plugin `jmeterDirectoryPath` is used as JMETER_HOME

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839890/1839360), I was able to solve a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340480/jmeter-jsr223postprocessor-running-file-with-script-relative-path).

Now, I can calculate this parameter once and re-use it as a user variable.

```
JMETER_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY=${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}
```

Its usage is `${JMETER_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY}`.
[image]

Interestingly, it works in both GUI mode and NON GUI mode (from command line).

Comment: Thanks! Even shorter:
`${__BeanShell(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir())}`