# How to get the name of JMX Jmeter filename in a variable

Tags: variables, jmeter, jmx

I want to use the name of the jmeter test script (.jmx) in a listener so as to generate the result file in a dynamic way. Can you please tell me what is the Jmeter variable for that purpose?

Used ${fileName} which didn't work

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via [Beanshell scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) like:

1. GUI mode

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;

   String scriptName = GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();
   vars.put("scriptName", scriptName);
   ```
2. non-GUI mode

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

   String scriptName = FileServer.getFileServer().getScriptName();
   vars.put("scriptName", scriptName);
   ```

Put the code snippet of your choice into any "Beanshell" test element (sampler, pre/post processor, or assertion), it will get .jmx test script name and store it into `${scriptName}` variable.

To learn more about Beanshell scripting in JMeter check out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Answer (score 2):

The variable that holds the test plan name is `${__TestPlanName}`

Ref: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__TestPlanName

Comment: This is the name of the test plan (root element of the tree), not the name of the JMX file.

Answer (score 2):

Below would work irrespective of GUI / Non GUI mode:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
import java.io.File;

String testPlanFile = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() +
                       File.separator +
                       FileServer.getFileServer().getScriptName();

props.put("testPlanFile", testPlanFile);
```

Use this as ${__P(testPlanFile)} - Adding it as var would not work across all threads. From http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html -

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a
>   thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be
>   referenced using the __P or __property function.