# jMeter JSR223PostProcessor - running file with script - relative path

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a jMeter JSR223PostProcessor  script which parses and validates response.

```
        <JSR223PostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223PostProcessor" testname="CitiesAssertion" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Asserts that actual cities are equal to expected cities</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="script">

expectedCities = [&quot;Prague&quot;, &quot;Brno&quot;, &quot;Ostrava&quot;, &quot;Berlin&quot;, &quot;Minsk&quot;, &quot;Warsaw&quot;] as Set

responseData = prev.getResponseData();
responseDataParsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(responseData);
actualCities = responseDataParsedJson as Set

log.info(&quot;actualCities: {}&quot;, actualCities);

// Assert may not work.
assert actualCities == expectedCities;

if (actualCities != expectedCities) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(&quot;actualCities are not equal to expectedCities. actualCities:  $actualCities, expectedCountries: $expectedCities&quot;)
}

            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
        </JSR223PostProcessor>
```

**I want to move the code of this script into a separate file and call it from jMeter step.**

Now, it says it cannot find the script file.

```
020-08-10 14:31:50,969 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, CitiesAssertion
javax.script.ScriptException: Script file 'C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\.\groovy\CitiesAssertion.groovy' does not exist or is unreadable for element:CitiesAssertion
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:205) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:940) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:572) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

When I open this script via jMeter UI, it will make **script file / file name** absolute path, which I do not want.

[image: cities_assertion]

---

[How to get the absolute folder location of a Jmeter .jmx project file from within itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809422/how-to-get-the-absolute-folder-location-of-a-jmeter-jmx-project-file-from-withi)

It says how to find script location in script. I thought that there would be a variable or parameter that points to the script location. I tried to have a debug element with **jMeter properties=true** and **jMeter variables=true**, etc, but it did not help (I did not find a variable or param pointing out to the location of test folder).

---

### Some idea

It turns out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31164646/1839360
that I can have a script at the beginning which resolves the location of jmx file and stores into into a variable. Then I can use this variable as a starting point of script location. It looks a bit complex though: I want to run jmeter from GUI and from command line, therefore I have to resolve `GUI mode` or `non GUI mode`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839890/1839360), it works with NON GUI and GUI modes as well - tested in jMeter UI and in docker.

1. In users variables, I added

`JMETER_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY=${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}`

[image: user variable]

2. Before groovy file name, I put `${JMETER_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY}`

for example, `JMETER_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY/ScriptName.groovy`.

[image: assert cities groovy script in a separate file]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just remove `./` from your script path so it would be just `groovy/CitiesAssertion.groovy`, this way the script location will be relative to the JMeter's base directory

   [image]
2. If you want to proceed with your scripting approach consider migrating to [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function
3. There is no `AssertionResult` shorthand in JSR223 PostProcessor, you might want to switch to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)

Comment: It did not work for me in GUI. I had an exception in log
`javax.script.ScriptException: Script file 'C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\groovy\CitiesAssertion.groovy' does not exist or is unreadable for element:CitiesAssertion
 at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:205) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
 at`

Comment: I see, it may work, **if** your script file is in the same has root folder of jmeter. For example, you have jMeter installed locally, and you put jmeter project file and script folder (groovy) inside local installation of jMeter. Or I am missing something...