# jmeter.functions.FileToString not finding file location

Tags: json, maven, jmeter, load-testing

In JMeter I am passing multiple JSON inputs as body, Variable name is defined as JSON_FILE and coming from CSV Data Config

```
${__FileToString(${__eval(${JSON_FILE})}.json,,)}
```

CSV Data

```
designO1015643320
.
.
designO1077673985
designO1088516727
```

Running load test from Jmeter **UI** works fine, but running as **mvn** project is giving error about `FileNotFoundException` even though .csv file and .json files are in same folder as .jmx file

**Error from .jmx.log:**

> WARN  - jmeter.functions.FileToString: Could not read file: designO1015643320.json File 'designO1015643320.json' does not exist java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'designO1015643320.json' does not exist

**Response in .jtl:**

> httpSample t="4" lt="0" ts="1508530091457" s="false" lb="CreateDesign_PUT" rc="Non HTTP response code: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException" rm="Non HTTP response message: End of sequence" tn="Design_APIs 1-1" dt="text" by="1822" ng="1" na="1"/>

Comment: since you don't specify path to the file, it's looking for it in current directory. When you running locally and using Maven, current directory is most likely different, hence it can't find that file.
You have to pass path somehow, or make it universal for both cases (e.g. absolute, or available on PATH)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter GUI default relative path is the bin folder

> Relative paths are resolved relative to the current working directory (which defaults to the bin/ directory).

Maven search in different default path for files `src/test/jmeter` directory

See [guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin):

> in the src/test/jmeter directory. When running the project, the JMeter Maven plugin searches for tests to run in this directory.

And you can find this path [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809422/how-to-get-the-absolute-folder-location-of-a-jmeter-jmx-project-file-from-withi)

Answer (score 0):

I heard [Groovy is a new black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so I would recommend replacing your __FileToString() function with [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the Groovy equivalent of dynamically getting the file path relative to Maven's plugin current working directory would be something like:

```
${__groovy(new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty('file.separator') + vars.get('JSON_FILE') + '.json').text,)}
```

See [JavaDoc on FileServer class](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) for more details.